# SVJour documentclass and amsmath package

Tags: packages

I am using TexShop v 3.99 on High Sierra OS 10.13.4, MacBook Pro.

illustrates the problem I encountered in the environment above.
I had no issues with older Mac and OS.
The article documentclass works just fine.[image: Minimal Working Example]
Could someone give me a hint?
[image: Error Log]
Many thanks, Rauan Akylzhanov.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you obtain `svjour.cls`?

Comment: Instructions for authors in Text subsection here http://www.springer.com/physics/theoretical%2C+mathematical+%26+computational+physics/journal/220?detailsPage=pltci_2297503.

Comment: The FTP site doesn't answer. :-(

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. It used to work about 5 months ago. I will give a link soon.

Comment: It would be easier if you posted the example and log as text not as an image but it appears to show amsmath.sty being input twice, which is not supposed to ever happen

Comment: @egreg it's on ctan https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/springer/svjour/cmp?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

The `svcmp.clo` option file defines `\intertext` If you are allowed to use `amsmath` with this journal you could undefine the command before loading `amsmath`

```
\documentclass[cmp,referee]{svjour}

\let\intertext\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear David Carlisle. I need to double-check with the author instructions. Your suggestion seems very reasonable and I will try  it ASAP. Many thanks.